# meta-iot-cloud - az - runpy issue (yocto)

Tags: linux, python, azure

I've built and installed meta-iot-cloud and flashed it to a gateway,
however, when I'm trying to run "az" I'm getting the following error:
"Could not import runpy module". 
Anyone else built this layer or encountered this issue and has any tips I could use?
I have both python2.7 and python3.5 installed, if I set the path to 2.7 I get the mentioned error, if I set it to 3.5 I'm getting an invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that runpy wasn't included in the installation.